# A Question of Taste

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

On one of her many visits to Pompeii, TV-presenter, Dame Mary Beard met an Italian chef who was making fish-sauce, garum, according to the original Roman recipe. Upon tasting this culinary delight Dame Mary's face contorted and twisted-up into the grimace-from-Hell. The inference: garum must have been/ is an acquired taste. How is this concept to be expressed in Latin?

Given that an acquired taste is a self-conditioned response induced by repeated exposure to the stimulant, a wild guess could be:

> "sapor assuetus" = "an accustomed taste".

Alternativlely, using verb, "assuefacio" = "to accustom"; in the passive sense, "assuefieri" = "to accustom oneself" (Oxford), in an ablative absolute construction which removes the requirement for a reflexive pronoun:

> "sapore assuefacto" = "with the taste (having been) accustomed by oneself".

The hope is that the (passive) ablative absolute will retain the advantage ("oneself") from the passive infinitive and that this AA sounds better, in Latin, than it does in English.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would parse the word 'taste' in 'acquired taste' as having the meaning 'preference', not 'flavour'. It's confusing, of course, because if a food is an acquired taste that means you must acquire the preference (taste) for the food's flavour (taste). But this means using *sapor* feels off to me.

Comment: The problem with *assuetus* is that it means "customary, usual." Not exactly logical, given the meaning of *assuescere*, but that's what it means.

Comment: @dbmag9 you're right, but who says we have to translate "acquired taste" literally? It is clearly the *sapor* we're really talking about.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel But to me, an 'acquired taste[/flavour]' would be a flavour that something has acquired. Perhaps soup might acquire a curry taste after being in the fridge next to some curry, or a person might acquire a taste after bathing in herbs!

Comment: @dbmag9 well, Tony made no attempts to translate "acquire" literally either. The English expression, e.g. "oysters are an acquired taste" really means "oysters have a taste that one has to get used to."

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Maybe a gerundive is called for, then. Sapor adsuescendus? "A taste that requires getting used to"

Comment: @dbmag9: Thank you. I'm not sure about "preference"; isn't this used to compare one thing with another: "I prefer garum to ketchup."?

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Thank you. Oxford gives "assuetus-a-um" = "accustomed", hence my confidence in using it. I thought that the Latin for "acquire", "acquiro", would mean "to acquire" in the sense of "to receive/ get a letter". Do you have a thought on the AA, "sapore assuefacto",  retaining the reflexive nature of the passive infinitive, "assuefieri" = "to accustom oneself"?

Comment: @Kingshorsey: Excellent. I didn't think about the gerundive, hoping that the AA would cover it.

Comment: @dbmag9: In Gilbert & Sullivans opera **The Mikado**, *acquired taste* is given a special meaning by Katisha, where she says about herself: 
"I am an acquired taste – only the educated palate can appreciate me. I was educating his palate when he left me. (...) It takes years to train a man to love me."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ego dicam: Garum, vel potius sapor gari, *indiget consuetudine quadam*, i.e. propter *saporem consuetudine indigentem* illius clarissimi liquaminis distorsit labra illa doctissima eques Britannica.